# Rails server is not starting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I installed Ruby on Rails in my Windows 8 machine and created a project. When I tried to run the application, it gives this error:

> Could not find gem 'sass-rails (~> 4.0.2) x64-mingw32' in the gems available on
>   this machine.

Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

I reinstalled the gem files and ran bundle install but received the same result.

How can I fix this?

Comment: If you do `gem list --local` does it show sass-rails as being installed?  If so, what version does it show?

Comment: what is the output of `rvm list`

Comment: What does the line in your `Gemfile` look like for `sass-rails`? And what do you mean by the statement, *I reinstalled teh gem files and ran bundle install...*? Did you do something other than `bundle install` to install the gems?

Comment: when is run gem list --local there is name call sass-rails

Comment: yes i try to add mysql gems

Comment: How do you start the server? With 'bundle exec rails s' ?

Comment: did you try that advice from the error message? `bundle install` ? ;)